# Hibernate custom query where clause and parameter

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I want to use a custom query with the where clause to find records with the given parameter.

I made this in my repository:

```
@Query(value = "select * from link t where t.r_id = :rID", nativeQuery = true)
List<TRR> findByRID(@Param("riID") Integer rID);
```

link is the name of my table in mysql and r_id is a column in the link table.
I basically want to give rID as a parameter to find all rows wiht rID = 1.

How can I do this? I currently get more records than the ones with only rID = 1.
I couldn't find more info about this subject.

### Edit

I have 9 records in table link in my database with the r_id = 1.
But when I give 1 as a parameter it finds 5.

Comment: You select `link` and get result on list of `TRR` ? not clear for me

Comment: Why does your @Param value (riID) diff. with your parameter name in the query - rID? riID vs. rID